# equally configured galera clusters generating different query plans

Tags: performance, query-optimization, galera, query-planner

We have 2 instances of the same galera cluster, so the same database schema with a data difference of 1 month. respectively they are a staging and a production environment.

They run on an identical hardware configuration, same operating system, same galera version, same configuration as a 3 node configuration. The network latency is a non-problem each node resides on a different docker container on the same machine and they are regularly backed up.

There is a particularly heavy query that in the staging env takes up to 2 seconds to run, while on the production env actually gets up to 2 minutes and half. Examining the query plan the magnitude of the number of records  difference for each step is not that far apart, but the actual query plan varies in strategy in the 2 following steps:

staging (2s):

```
8   DERIVED b   ref bay_depend_id,bay_relies_on_id  bay_depend_id   4   rwms.l.bay_id   2   Using where
8   DERIVED b   ref bay_depend_id,bay_relies_on_id  bay_depend_id   4   rwms.l.bay_id   2   Using where
```

production (2mins):

```
8   DERIVED b   ALL bay_depend_id,bay_relies_on_id              1   Using where; Using join buffer (flat, BNL join)
8   DERIVED b   ALL bay_depend_id,bay_relies_on_id              1   Using where; Using join buffer (incremental, BNL join)
```

The query plan for all the other steps of the query is actually the same with the  difference being in the number of records, but at these 2 steps the actual evaluation strategy changes. And I can't really wrap my head around it, or on how to resolve this issue, mostly because every working condition is radically the same.

Comment: Does the "staging" cluster have fewer rows that the "production" cluster?

Answer (score 0):

How big are those tables?  (On *each* node.)

`EXPLAIN` is *not* consistent.  Your example of such is rather drastic and deserves more investigation.  Please provide the query, table size(s), and `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...`  Also `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Doing this *may* get them in sync:

```
 ANALYZE TABLE ...
```

It is fast and rebuilds the statistics for the table given.  Note:  There is no sharing of statistics between nodes, so do that on each node.